# test studio - new browser on fail

Tags: c#, testing, telerik-test-studio

I'm using a trial version of Teleriks Test Studio, and am running into a problem with it on my Silverlight application. My test is logging in, then attempting to add 100 new users from a data source.  I have run the test multiple times and every time it fails, it seems to do the same thing: it gets stuck with an `Unable to locate element` error, but my understanding was that if it fails, it should restart the test.  However, this is not the case.  Instead it just sits there, unable to find any other element

I should say this is an inconsistent error; this is always in a different stage of the test.  Sometimes it will run 10 tests perfectly, then the next one will fail.

Is there a way to cause a `close current browser and open new browser` on fail, or even add a step to close and open the browser as the first step?  How can I close and reopen the browser when the browser is not responding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Telerik's help forums:

```
[Setup]
if (Manager.Current.Browsers.Count > 1)
{
   Helpers.KillBrowserProcesses(_browserType);
}

if (ActiveBrowser == null || !Process.GetProcessesByName(_processName).Any())
{
   var retries = 0;
   bool browserOpened;
   do
   {
      try
      {
         browserOpened = true;
         Manager.LaunchNewBrowser(_browserType, true, ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized);
         retries = 0;
      }
      catch
      {
         retries++;
         browserOpened = false;
         Console.WriteLine("Restarting the browser. Retry {0} of {1}", retries,
                                      Configuration.Instance.BrowserOpeningRetries);
         if (Manager.Browsers.Count <= 0) continue;
            Helpers.KillBrowserProcesses(_browserType);
            //foreach (var browser in Manager.Browsers)
            //    browser.Close();
            //if (ActiveBrowser != null)
            //    ActiveBrowser.Close();
      }
   } 
   while (retries < Configuration.Instance.BrowserOpeningRetries && browserOpened == false);
}

public static void KillBrowserProcesses(BrowserType browserType)
{
   var browserProcesses = new Process[] {};
   switch (browserType)
   {
      case BrowserType.FireFox:
         browserProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox");
         break;
      case BrowserType.InternetExplorer:
         browserProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");
         break;
   }
   foreach (var browserProcess in browserProcesses)
   {
      try
      {
         browserProcess.Kill();
         browserProcess.WaitForExit();
      }
      catch
      {}
   }
}
```